# How to update database and let delay block reference delay duration to updated value?

Tags: anylogic

I have created a UI page for user to input the delay duration in edit boxes for certain activities at the simulation screen. [image: edit box set up] The input values should update the database value and amend the delay duration. However, while the database does get updated, the delay block in the main screen keeps capturing the non-updated database value (eg. initial database value is 100, then a user inputs 200. The database value updates to 200, however, my delay block still captures 100.) [image: delay block set up] Is this an issue with AnyLogic database or am I using it wrongly?

[image: Initial reading from database]
[image: Initial reading from database]
[image: Updated reading from database]
[image: Updated reading from database]

Comment: I can't tell you how many hours as a beginner I spent trying to debug models due to this issue. Please review the answer provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68302146/4019094 and consider using this approach instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify in the unique result formula that you do not want to make use of the cached result.

[image]
(This image is from the local AnyLogic help, you can search for "uniqueResult". I could not find it on the new online help.

The default value is to use true, i.e. use the previous value that was retrieved from the DB for the same query

Simply add false as the first argument in your `uniqueResult()` code.

Comment: Wow you are amazing! Thank you so much! I'm 100% certain I would never have found this solution on my own. Really thankful for your solution! *Bows*